# SQL GROUPING QUERY - H2 DataBase

Tags: sql, h2

I have a table with items, their properties, and those properties' values. I would like to construct a query that produces unique rows for each property having all the different values from the different items in a single row.

From
ITEM PROPERTY VALUE

To
PROPERTY item1Value item2Value item3Value ....

Has anyone solved this situation before?

Thanks in advance, regards!

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you need to do PIVOT table. below is the link that explains it in very good details.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

if you give your table definition with datatype i can help with query

Comment: Yes, that's what I need, but the explicit PIVOT command seems to be only available in MSSQL. I would need to do this pivoting manually.

Comment: PIVOT is on the roadmap but does not seem to be available yet: http://www.h2database.com/html/roadmap.html